# jQuery Slider with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slider

I'm a beginner in AngularJS and have some HTML & JS code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ktaras/v9sjL/7

Could somebody help me and explain why `ngModel.$modelValue` in my `link` function returns `NaN`?

I found some solution and getting model value from `scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel)`, but it seems to me so far from perfect...

Please, explain me how to do it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with the digest cycle, as if you wrap console.log(ngModel.$modelValue); within a $timeout (once injecting it into the directive) it evaluates fine. But this is hacky and would not recommend.

Instead of using require I think passing the ngModel into the directive with a two-way binding and attaching to the directives scope would be better.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PRg5h/1/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        Rating: {{rating}}
        <div slider ng-model="rating"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.rating = 50
});

myApp.directive('slider', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
          ngModel: '='
      },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      console.log(scope.ngModel);

      return $(elem).slider({
        range: "min",
        animate: true,
        value: scope.ngModel,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          return scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.ngModel = ui.value;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: _Instead of using require I think passing the ngModel into the directive with a two-way binding would be better._
Could you explain it in more detail please?

Comment: Sorry, I initially attached your javascript and fiddle to the answer. Have amended with mine.

Comment: @ktaras, my understanding of using 'require' in a directive is the ability to communicate with another directive's controller. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives has some good examples of this. Another thing, from your question it looked like you were trying to accomplish two-way binding yourself, when angular can handle this for you.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you! It works perfect and it seems to me like a better solution.

Comment: No problems. If you are starting out in Angular check out http://egghead.io, and also the angular documentation is worth reading https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: ...oh, and as I see you're new on stackoverflow, don't forget to accept correct answers to your questions too with the tick :-)